# hist.default "character(0)" error in R when trying to knit

Tags: r, knitr

I have a simple line of code to create a histogram that works fine in Rstudio, but when I try to knit I get the following error:

```
Error in hist.default(p, breaks = 20, col = "lavender", main = "P value histogram") : 
  character(0)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> hist -> hist.default
Execution halted
```

Any help to fix this is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post what the object `p` is with `dput()`?